# How to limit char length in bootstrap live search

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to add maxlenght to bootstraps bs-searchbox.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
</head>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row-fluid">
    <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
      <option data-subtext="Rep California">Tom Foolery</option>
      <option data-subtext="Sen California">Bill Gordon</option>
      <option data-subtext="Sen Massacusetts">Elizabeth Warren</option>
      <option data-subtext="Rep Alabama">Mario Flores</option>
      <option data-subtext="Rep Alaska">Don Young</option>
      <option data-subtext="Rep California" disabled="disabled">Marvin Martinez</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
   <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: What would be the point? If no results come up the search term is too long.

Comment: @isherwood actually the requirement is to set char limit but there is no option to set char limit. also updated bootstrap-3 tag.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. There's no option because it would serve no purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old version of `bootstrap-select` besides being vulnerable to various attacks it is quite out of date, updating it you can use the loading event and use `maxlength` for your purpose.

Example with `maxlength` = 6

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker().on('loaded.bs.select', function (e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
  $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu > .bs-searchbox > input').attr('maxlength','6');
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
</head>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row-fluid">
    <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
      <option data-subtext="Rep California">Tom Foolery</option>
      <option data-subtext="Sen California">Bill Gordon</option>
      <option data-subtext="Sen Massacusetts">Elizabeth Warren</option>
      <option data-subtext="Rep Alabama">Mario Flores</option>
      <option data-subtext="Rep Alaska">Don Young</option>
      <option data-subtext="Rep California" disabled="disabled">Marvin Martinez</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: I suggest reducing your answer to just that example. The other is faulty, in my view. No need to credit me. :)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Thank you so much will update my bootstrap select thank you :)